# What are these Cacti? Are they Healthy?

Tags: cactus

[image]

I bought two cacti from IKEA. I water them weekly. They seem happy. Not growing much but maybe a little. I don't know what they are or if I'm looking after them right. Please have a look at the pictures and help! Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVbA6.jpg)

Comment: They look fine to me. If you want them to grow, give them the maximum amount of sun you can. You can't overcook them. In winter, watering once a week may be too much, and risk the roots rotting. A plant that size won't come to any harm with no water at all for 3 or 4 months in the middle of winter and will have a "growth spurt" when you start watering again in spring..

Answer (score 1):

These are cacti from the genus *Mammillaria*, which particular species I don't know (the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammillaria) has a lot of species). Best is to wait for the flowers, then it will be easier to identify which species it is.

Cacti like a lot of sun, so a window facing south would be ideal (if you live on the Northern hemisphere that is).

Also they don't like a lot of water, once every 3 or 4 weeks would be okay. Try to get the soil to dry up between waterings. In winter, try to put them in a cool place and don't water them at all for months.

Answer (score 0):

This plant is in dire need of more light. The body is stretched and light green at the top. They should be more globular (round) like the plant below.

Water when the top of the soil is dry to the touch. Slowly introduce it to more direct sun, the more the better.

Have you ever gotten flowers?

[image: Mammillaria mystax]